# saving file as .pdf as recieved in http response error

Tags: java, pdf, google-drive-api, pdf-generation, httpresponse

For my project i need to download a pdf file from google drive using java
I get my httpresponse code 200 and by using following method i store it in abc.pdf file

```
String url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id="+fileid+"&export=download";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    OutputStream f0 = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Darshil\\Desktop\\abc.pdf",true);
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(inputLine);
                byte b[]=inputLine.getBytes();
                //System.out.println(b);
                f0.write(b);
    }
    in.close();
            f0.close();
```

But when i try to open abc.pdf in my adobe reader x i get following error:

```
There was an error opening this document.The file is damaged and could not be repaired
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be directly accessing the Google drive using Raw HTTP requests.

You may be better of using the Google Drive SDK. [This link](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads) contains good examples to address the use cases you state in your question.

However if you do want to stick to your technique then you should not be using a `BufferedReader.readLine()`. This is because the PDF file is a binary finally that would depend upon the correct byte sequences to be preserved in order to be read correctly by the PDF reader software. Hopefully the below technique should help you:

```
//read in chunks of 2KB
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int bytesRead = 0;
try(InputStream is = conn.getInputStream())
{

     try(DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.pdf"))
     {
         while((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
         {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }     
     }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //handle exception
}
```

Note that I am using the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement in Java 7

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but it will be help if u can suggest with following method also as when i tried to download file using alt-media one even from my browser it gave me http error 403 even after oauth authentication.

Comment: @DHRUVIPANDYA I have updated my answer wth a sample code snippet. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: @DHRUVIPANDYA Great!! Glad to be of help!!